# Explain why "A Fate who didn’t finish the material (5)" is Cloth

Tags: cryptic-clues, explanation

> A Fate who didn’t finish the material (5)

Answer: CLOTH

This is a cryptic clue from The Post (NZ) and appeared on the 22nd Jun 2023

Answer (score 21):

One of the [Fates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fates) of Greek mythology was **[Clotho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clotho)**. If you don't quite finish that word, you get the word cloth (defined by "the material").

Comment: For reference: Clotho was the spinner, Lachesis was the weaver and Atropos was the one with the scissors. At least according to Hesiod

Comment: It's worth adding for anyone new to cryptic crosswords, that this is a type of cryptic clue called a Double Definition. So reading the clue "A Fate who didn’t finish the material (5)" as "'A Fate who didn't finish', 'the material' (5)" is what guides you to the solution.

Comment: @StuperUser Not a double definition. The definition is just "the material", and the rest is wordplay (letter removal).

Comment: @jafe You're right. How would you categorise the clue? A Deletion?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. This makes more sense now.